# Could not find a match for std::string::basic_string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::char_traits<char>>, std::istreambuf_iterator<char, std::

Tags: c++, solaris, solaris-studio

The following innocuous function fails to compile on Solaris Studio 12.3

```
#undef _RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#define _RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES
std::string FetchData(const std::string& fname)
    {
        std::ifstream fin(fname.c_str());
        std::string data;
        if (fin)
        {
            data = std::string((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(fin)),
                std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
        }
        return data;
    }

int main()
{
    return 0;
}
```

which fails with the error message

> Could not find a match for
>   `std::string::basic_string(std::istreambuf_iterator<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>>, std::istreambuf_iterator<char,
>   std::char_traits<char>>)`needed in `OOTest::FetchData(const std::string
>   &)`.

Now I checked the file `std::string` and found the following

```
#ifndef _RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES
    template <class _InputIterator>
    basic_string (_InputIterator, _InputIterator, const _Allocator& _RWSTD_DEFAULT_ARG(_Allocator()));
```

SO I guess, `std::string` has a declaration for the overload

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

which should have matched

```
template< class InputIt >
basic_string( InputIt first, InputIt last, 
              const Allocator& alloc = Allocator() );
```

but unfortunately it didn't.

So I have two questions

1. Why doesn't  my construction via `std::istreambuf_iterator<char>` doesn't match?
2. What is this  macro `_RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES` for?

**Note**

1. Based on the comment, I tried to generate the pre-processor output by running `CC -E test.cpp > pre.out` and found, the iterator version was not generated. So I tried undefining `_RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES` but that didn't help.

Comment: Can you check preprocessor output to see if that macro is in fact skipping that constructor declaration?

Comment: @aschepler: As per the pre-processor output, the iterator version of the constructor was not generated, so I tried undefining the macro _RWSTD_NO_MEMBER_TEMPLATES , but that didn't help

Comment: Your standard library implementation is probably outdated. Use a different implementation. See [here](https://community.oracle.com/message/9936913).

Comment: Hello, did you find a solution for that problem which I am also facing?